# How can I scan all my fields in MySQL for form input

Tags: php

In my script below, the user inputs a form and rows are returned from a MYSQL table if rows are similar to inputted by the user. I am building a search engine and everything is based on rank. But I want to be able to adjust the code below to see how many times the word 'iPad' for example comes up with the row fields, which are 'title', 'description', 'keywords' and 'link'. If so, I want that row to return higher than say a row that has a higher id, but only mentions iPad once in all of the fields combined.
My code is below: 
            Terms together query:
            $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE ";

```
$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
$i = 0; 
foreach ($terms as $each) {
      if ($i++ !== 0){
            $query .= " AND "; 
      }
      $query .= "title LIKE '%{$each}%' OR link LIKE '%{$each}%' OR  keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' OR description LIKE '%{$each}%' ";

}

   $query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));

echo '<p class="time">Qlick showed your results in ' . number_format($secs,2) . ' seconds.</p>';     

 $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $description = $row['description'];
            $keywords = $row['keywords'];
            $link = $row['link'];
            $rank = $row['rank'];


   Seperate Terms Query

            $query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

    $terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
    $i = 0; 
    foreach ($terms as $each) {
          if ($i++ !== 0){
                $query .= " OR "; 
          }
          $query .= "title LIKE '%{$each}%' OR link LIKE '%{$each}%' OR  keywords LIKE '%{$each}%' OR description LIKE '%{$each}%' ";
      }

    // Don't append the ORDER BY until after the loop

          $query = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows > 0) {

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                $id = $row['id'];
                $title = $row['title'];
                $description = $row['description'];
                $keywords = $row['keywords'];
                $link = $row['link'];
                $rank = $row['rank'];
```

Comment: You are nesting mysql queries which is not a good idea.  It may work for a small dataset, but once you get past a couple hundred rows, it's game over.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to do this using an auxiliary field on which to run a `FULLTEXT` query, in which you would save all textual data:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html
```

The alternative is to run the filtering in MySQL and the ranking in PHP. You might squeeze some performance by running a single LIKE on the concatenated field.

By the way, your code above lacks parentheses in the LIKE, so that the results won't be correct: you mustn't ask `WHERE field1 LIKE 'x' OR field2 LIKE 'x' AND field1 LIKE 'y' OR...`, you must state `WHERE (field1 LIKE 'x' OR field2 LIKE 'x') AND (field1 LIKE 'y' OR...)`.

```
// Here we search for ALL terms (all must be present at least once)
// use ' OR ' to ask that at least one term must be present once.
$where = array();
foreach($terms as $term)
    $where[] = "( CONCAT(title,'|',link,'|',keywords) LIKE '%{$term}%')";
$query .= ' WHERE ' . '('.implode(' AND ', $where).')';
```

Now in the OR case you could do a simple ranking on the number of matched terms (with AND the number is always the total number of terms):

```
$select_fields[] '(' . implode ('+', $where) . ') AS ranking';
```

Otherwise in SQL you would need recourse to a *really* ugly hack:

```
(LENGTH(
    REPLACE(CONCAT(title,'|',link,'|',keywords),'{$term}','')
) - LENGTH(CONCAT(title,'|',link,'|',keywords)))/LENGTH('{$term}');
```

This above calculates the difference between the total length of the text where the search is to be done and the total length of the same text, *with search string removed*. The difference is of course proportional to how many times the search string is there: if the string is 8 characters long, a difference of 32 would mean that it is present four times. Dividing the length difference by the length of the term, we obtain the number of hits.

The problem is that for several terms you have to complicate the query enormously, and it might be really expensive to run:

```
$select_fields = array('*');

$where = array();
$rank  = array();
foreach($terms as $term)
{
    // assume $term is NOT QUOTED
    $search  = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
    $concat  = "CONCAT(title,'|',link,'|',keywords)";

    $where[] = "(${concat} LIKE '%{$search}%')";
    $rank[]  = "(LENGTH(REPLACE(${concat},'{$search}',''))
           - LENGTH(${concat}))/LENGTH('{$search}')";
}
$select_fields[] = "(".implode(",", $rank).") AS ranking";

$query .= "SELECT " . implode(',', $select_fields)
       .  ' FROM scan WHERE (' . implode(' AND ', $where)   . ')';
```